# Pattern printing in java

Tags: java, loops, for-loop

I want to print patterns in java like:

**Pattern 1:**

> 1
> 2 6
> 3 7 10
> 4 8 11 13
> 5 9 12 14 15

**Pattern 2:**

> 1
> 3 2
> 4 5 6
> 10 9 8 7
> 11 12 13 14 15
> 21 20 19 18 17 16

But I am not getting it and any help on the algorithm will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance and of course thanks to stackoverflow.

Comment: Good luck with that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you are. This is program for your first pattern :-

```
public class PrintPattern1 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        int l=4;

        for(i=1;i<6;i++){
            System.out.println();
            k=i;
            l=4;
            for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                System.out.print(" "+k);
                k=k+l;
                l=l-1;
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

and this is program for your second pattern :-

```
public class PrintPattern2 {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int i=0;
        int j=0;
        int k=0;
        int l=1;

        for(i=1;i<7;i++){
            System.out.println();
            if(i%2==0){
                k=l+i-1;
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                    System.out.print(" "+k);
                    k=k-1;
                    l=l+1;
                }
            }else{
                k=l;
                for(j=1;j<=i;j++){
                    System.out.print(" "+k);
                    k=k+1;
                    l=l+1;
               }
            }
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Do not forget to accept my answer by clicking right mark on top left corner of it. Happy Coding :)

Comment: Thank you sir when I compare my code with yours I saw that I was very close but just gave up.

Comment: @RishavChoudhuri: It happens to all.  Never give up. Keep trying. All the Best :)

Comment: I will.Thank you all for your support.

Answer (score 0):

The first pattern appears to have a fixed length. The second could go on indefinitely. This code generates them:

```
    int lineCount = 5;
    for (int i = 1; i <= lineCount; ++i) { //
        int n = i;
        for (int j = 1; j <= i; ++j) {
            System.out.print(n + " ");
            n += (lineCount - j);
        }
        System.out.println();
    }


    boolean direction = true; //true for increasing order
    int lineLength = 1;
    int currentStartingPoint = 1;
    while(true) {
        if(direction) {
            for (int i = 0; i < lineLength; ++i) {
                System.out.print(currentStartingPoint + i + " ");
            }
            currentStartingPoint += lineLength++;
        }
        else {
            for (int i = currentStartingPoint + lineLength - 1; i >= currentStartingPoint; --i) {
                System.out.print(i + " ");
            }
            currentStartingPoint += lineLength++;
        }

        direction = !direction;
        System.out.println();
    }
```